# How to fix The following _CastError was thrown building: type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>' in type cast

Tags: java, flutter, dart

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'UI_Tool/size_fit.dart';

class Gallery extends StatefulWidget {

@override
_GalleryState createState() => _GalleryState();

}

class _GalleryState extends State<Gallery> {

pic() async {

var url = "http://120.76.247.131:8081/findAllImages";
var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
return json.decode(response.body);
}
@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
pic();
 }
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('Gallery'),

  ),

  body: FutureBuilder(
    future : pic(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);
      return snapshot.hasData
          ? ListView.builder(
          itemCount:2,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            List list = pic() as List;
            return Card(
                child: ListTile(
                title: Container(
                width: 100,
                height: 100,
                child: Image.network(
                "http://120.76.247.131:8081/findAllImages/%7Blist[index][%22image%22]%7D%22)"
            ),
            ),
            ));
          })
          : Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      );
    },
  ),
);
  }
  }
```

I had tried to add  behind the future and it doesn't solve the problem. Moreover, there is a problem with the itemcount, so I left it with a number instead of add snapshot.data!.length() because I am not sure why there is an error with snapshot.data!.length() for itemcount.

Comment: Please try to replace
List list = pic() as List;
with
List list = snapshot.data as List;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is full working code.

At first because pic() returns Future,
you need to use 'await' or 'then' to get a response.
https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await

Because of that, below sentence cause error as you provided.
But because it is not necessary in this case, I get rid of this.

```
List list = pic() as List;
```

If you want use pic() method, just call like below.
(But in this case, you cannot call like this.)

```
List list = await pic()
```

You've already used 'FutureBuilder', you don't need to call pic() again.
You just use snapdata's data incase of snapdata has a data.

[image]

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() {
  print('onStart');
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: Gallery(),
    );
  }
}

class Gallery extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _GalleryState createState() => _GalleryState();
}

class _GalleryState extends State<Gallery> {
  pic() async {
    var url = "http://120.76.247.131:8081/findAllImages";
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    return json.decode(response.body);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    pic();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Gallery'),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: pic(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);
          return snapshot.hasData
              ? ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: (snapshot.data! as Map)['data'].length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    // List list = pic() as List;
                    print((snapshot.data! as Map)['data'][index]);
                    return Card(
                        child: ListTile(
                      title: Container(
                        width: 100,
                        height: 100,
                        child: Image.network(
                            (snapshot.data! as Map)['data'][index]['image']),
                      ),
                    ));
                  })
              : Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: itemCount: snapshot.data['data'].length,                                                                              
There is an error: The method ‘[]’ can’t be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be ‘null’.                                                                                                                                              May I know how to solve it?

Comment: Aha~ you are now using Null-Safety environment. 
Just change like this. snapshot.data!['data'].length

Comment: Ok, but after I changed to this, there is a new error:    The operator ‘[]’ isn’t defined for the type ‘Object’.

Comment: Ok, thanks @KuKu. It solves the whole thing and may I know what causes this problem so I can be more caution next time?

Comment: Ok, thanks @KuKu for explaining in details.

Comment: I had faced another problem with displaying the video from Mysql online server database, here's the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69047403/flutter-dio-why-is-it-unable-to-display-video-from-mysql-online-server-database, is it possible for you to solve the problem?